# MySQL order by is ignored in select from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have two tables: Students and Parents, in one-parent-to-many-students relationship. Both have a parentID. The parents table is used as my login. It has parent ID, name, email address and password. Students has a slew of fields. I need to select all parents and include names of their students (and this part works fine). I want to be able to order by either the parent name or parent email. However, my order by statement is being ignored, and $rows is ordered by the parentID. Here is my code:

```
$query = 'SELECT 
  Parents.parentID, 
  Parents.parentName, 
  Parents.Email, 
  Students.nickName,
  Students.Lname
FROM Parents, Students
WHERE Parents.parentID=Students.parentID
  AND Parents.status=:active
ORDER BY :orderby ASC' ;
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':orderby', $myOrderby, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':active', 'active', PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

I have tried

```
$myOrderby = 'parentName' ;
$myOrderby = 'Parents.parentName' ;
$myOrderby = 'Email' ;
$myOrderby = 'Parents.Email' ;
```

(Yes, above the query) and the result is the same regardless: It returns data in the order of the parentID. I have searched for over an hour looking for a solution, and found nothing. Thanks for any assistance you can offer.

Comment: Probably because it's the moral equivalent of `ORDER BY 'Constant String'`, so the `ORDER BY` clause is treating all rows as equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One cannot use variables inside the ORDER BY clause. One has to construct the actual query. Like this:

```
if ($conditionA) { $orderby = 'field_name' } ;
elseif ($condiB) { $orderby = 'field_email' } ;
else             { $orderby = 'field_default' } ;

$query = "SELECT fieldnames FROM tables WHERE whatever ORDER BY $orderby" ;
```

Which puts the correct fieldname directly into the query and all is well.
YAY!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT 
  Parents.parentID, 
  Parents.parentName, 
  Parents.Email, 
  Students.nickName,
  Students.Lname
FROM Parents, Students
WHERE Parents.parentID=Students.parentID
  AND Parents.status=:active
ORDER BY
    CASE :orderby
       WHEN 'Name' THEN Parents.parentName
       WHEN 'EMail' THEN Parents.Email
    END ASC
```

And then set `$myOrderby` to either `'Name'` or `'EMail'`.

You can expand this to more columns, provided all of the columns have the same data types. If you had a mixture of, say, string and numeric data by which you wanted to do the ordering, you would instead do:

```
ORDER BY
    CASE :orderby
       WHEN 'Name' THEN Parents.parentName
       WHEN 'EMail' THEN Parents.Email
    END ASC,
    CASE :orderby
       WHEN 'NumericColumn' THEN NumericColumn
    END
```

Because the result of each `CASE` expression must be of, or convertible to, a single type - and you wouldn't want to force the numeric values to be compared as strings - placing 10 between 1 and 2.

Comment: Will try this tomorrow. Not sure what you mean by: Moral equivalent of ORDER BY 'Constant String'.

Comment: @WynSnow - I meant that what you were trying was about the same as writing `ORDER BY 'a'` - it wouldn't have any effect, because it's a *string*, not the *name* of a column - so every row has the same value for the sorting process.

Comment: Actually no, it WAS the name of a column. I found the solution somewhere else: basically, one cannot use variables inside the order by clause. One has to construct the query directly. Like this:

    if ($condA) { $orderby = 'field_name' };
    elseif ($condB) { $orderby = 'field_email' } ;

    $query = "SELECT fieldnames FROM tables ORDER BY $orderby" ;

This directly inserts the correct $orderby variable into the query and all is well.

Comment: @WynSnow - you had a *string* that happened to *contain* the name of a column. If you had `$var = "1 + 2";` in your (PHP?) code, would you expect `$var` to be equal to `3`?

Comment: okay, clearly I don't understand the difference between a "string that contains the name of a column" and an actual name of a column. And BTW, I tried your CASE suggestion and that did not work for me either. Constructing the $query does work.